# In Gmail, when creating a group, how can I specify which email address to use for a contact with multiple email addresses?

Tags: gmail, google-contacts

How to specify which email address should be used for a group created in Gmail Contacts?

In the group list, there is a drop-down field that looks like it could be used for selecting the email to use for this group. But it has no effect.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is summed up in the postscript to [this post](https://equalsdrummond.name/2015/04/25/how-to-specify-the-email-address-to-use-in-a-google-contacts-group/) by Drummond Reed here:

> Postscript: logging into my personal Gmail account tonight, I noticed they have a new UI for Contacts. And guess what? **The group member email address selection feature is gone again.**
>
> What is Google thinking?

There is a workaround, as detailed in [a comment](https://equalsdrummond.name/2015/04/25/how-to-specify-the-email-address-to-use-in-a-google-contacts-group/#comment-33291) to that post. **Use the old Contacts interface**.

Here's the full workaround:

1. In left panel of Contacts page, at bottom of menu under your groups listing, click `More`
2. In the drop-down that open up, click `Leave the Contacts preview`
3. Now, in old UI, click your group
4. Click the user whose email you want to set
5. In user contact page, under user's name, you will see tags with groups user belongs to.
6. Click drop-down button for tag.
7. Choose the email address you want to use for that user for that group.

After all, why use one step when you can use seven?

Comment: I can not find the old interface now. What is Google thinking?

Answer (score 3):

With Google's new updated Contacts I was unable to access the old interface as described by klenwell.

**My workaround is as follows:**

1. Select the contact whose email address you wish to specify.
2. In the top right of the popup window which opens, click the pen icon to **Edit contact**
3. The first email address listed is the email address that will be used when a group email is sent. To change the email address order:

   - Click the blue "+" button to the right of the last email address
   - Select and cut the top email address
   - Paste it into the empty field created by clicking the "+" button
   - Repeat the above until the email address required for the group is at the top of the list

**Limitations:** This workaround only serves to change the contact's primary email address - this email address will be used in **all** groups. I was unable to find a way to specify different email addresses for different groups.